# Simple math using arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm messing around with JavaScript and am trying out objects, functions & arrays.  I'd like to know if someone has tips about making it better, shorter, or has a better solution for what I have thought about for now. What I've tried to do is just do simple math (+ and -) using arrays as input for numbers.  It all works, but I'm just wondering if it could be even better and/or cleaner.

```
//Write the result
function ap(n) {
    $(".value").append(n);
}

// Make sure the input is a number
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function doMath(options) {
    var defaults = {
        method: 'add'
    };
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    // Add
    if(options.method == 'add') {
        var n = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<options.numbers.length; i++) {
            if(isNumber(options.numbers[i])) {
                n = n + options.numbers[i];
            }
            if(i===options.numbers.length-1) {
                ap(n);
            }
        }
    }

    // Subtract
    if(options.method == 'subtract' ) {

        for (var i=0; i<options.numbers.length; i++) {
            if(i===0) {
                n = options.numbers[0];
            } else {
                if(isNumber(options.numbers[i])) {
                    n = n - options.numbers[i];
                }
            }

            if(i===options.numbers.length-1) {
                ap(n);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Print the result
doMath({'numbers': [10,5,2,2], 'method':'subtract'});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid mixing calculations with input/output. It would be better if your `doMath()` would not call the output function `ap()` directly, but instead would just return the result of its calculations:

```
ap(doMath({'numbers': [10,5,2,2], 'method':'subtract'}));
```

Of course the `ap` itself is a lousy name for a function, but it's more of a helper in here I guess.

I see no reason why you would use and options object instead of passing in just two parameters, but even when you use an options object, it would be simpler to extract its values into local variables and work with these. One can also easily drop the use of `$.extend` in favor of simple `||` operator, which is the canonical way of implementing default values for parameters:

```
    var method = options.method || "add";
    var numbers = options.numbers;
```

Another step to simplify code is to filter out the invalid numbers before doing any calculations on them. `Array.filter` helps us here:

```
var validNumbers = numbers.filter(isNumber);
```

The actual calculation can be easily implemented with `Array.reduce`. First we can define functions `add` and `subtract`

```
var methods = {
    add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
    subtract: function(a, b) { return a - b; }
};
```

And then using `Array.reduce` we can apply them for the whole array:

```
validNumbers.reduce(methods.add);
// or
validNumbers.reduce(methods.subtract);
```

Pulling it all together:

```
function doMath(options) {
    var method = options.method || "add";
    var numbers = options.numbers;

    var validNumbers = numbers.filter(isNumber);

    var methods = {
        add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
        subtract: function(a, b) { return a - b; }
    };

    return validNumbers.reduce(methods[method]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function doMath(options) {
    var defaults = {
        method: 'add'
    };
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var n = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<options.numbers.length; i++) {
        if(isNumber(options.numbers[i])) {
            if(options.method == 'add' || i == 0) {
                n += options.numbers[i];
            }
            else if(options.method == "subtract"){
                n -= options.numbers[i];
            }
        }
    }
    ap(n);
}
```

This code is making many assumptions, for example that `options.numbers` is defined, but for the lack of the exact definition of the problem you are trying to solve this looks at least shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (e.g. if you cannot use the Array-Methods):

```
function doMath(options){
    var result;
    var operations={
        add: function(){
            var result=0;
            return function(o){
                return result+=o;
            }
        }(),
        substract: function(){
            var result=0;
            return function(o){
                return result-=o;
            }
        }()
    };

    var fn=operations[options.method]||operations.add;

    while(number=options.numbers.pop()){
        result=fn(number);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bAbGR/).

Not quite as elegant as `Array.reduce()` but does its job.
(Validation for numbers omitted)